# Drop support for Cocoapods for a library

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, dependency-management, swift-package-manager

I want to drop the support for Cocoapods for a library I'm developing. The library is several years old, so it has a `.xcworkspace` file, an `Example` and all the source files are into a `Pods` folder. It already supports Swift Package Manager and I want to go all in with it. Is there a procedure for this or should it be done manually?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it manually. Have to delete the pod files, and remove all pods. Then add through Swift Package Manager.